# Scriban function to convert snake case to pascal/camel case

Tags: scriban

I'm trying to generate some C# code using Scriban templates. The DB I'm using is postgresql, so my tables and properties are all in snake_case. I managed to make a function to convert snake case to pascal case:

```
{{ for word in EntityName | string.split "_" -}} {{~word | string.capitalize}} {{-end}}
```

This does convert *entity_name* to the desired *EntityName*.

And camel case:

```
{{func split(en)
    ret en | string.split "_"
end}}

{{for index in 0..@split(EntityName).size -}} 
    {{-if index == 0}} {{~@split(EntityName)[index]-}} {{-else-}} {{-@split(EntityName)[index] | string.capitalize-}} {{-end-}}
{{-end}}
```

However, I need to use this function multiple times in my template, therefore I wanted to make a function I can use throughout the template, just like the split(en) function I use for the camel case conversion. So I could do something like this everywhere I need it:

```
{{ @convert(EntityName) }}
```

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution to my problem. Instead of creating functions in the template itself, I make a ScriptObject.

```
public class ScribanHelper : ScriptObject
{
    public static string ConvertToPascalCase(string word)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
            return string.Empty;

        return string.Join("", word.Split('_')
                     .Select(w => w.Trim())
                     .Where(w => w.Length > 0)
                     .Select(w => w.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + w.Substring(1).ToLower()));
    }
}
```

And then I push this to the scriban context to use it in the templates.

```
var context = new TemplateContext { MemberRenamer = member => member.Name };

var scriptObject = new ScribanHelper();
context.PushGlobal(scriptObject);

var templateString = File.ReadAllText(templateSetting.Name);
var template = Template.Parse(templateString);

var entityScriptObject = new ScriptObject();
entityScriptObject.Import(entity, renamer: member => member.Name);
context.PushGlobal(entityScriptObject);

var result = template.Render(context);
```

And then I can easily use it in the templates.

```
{{-func pc(name)
    ret convert_to_pascal_case name
end}}

{{@pc(EntityName)}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer. You still need to create the function and can use word.Pascalize() inside it.